# How to pass value from def to a view openerp

Tags: python, view, odoo

This is my code:

```
def view_purchase(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'diary_purchase',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'context': "{'name': 'my purchase'}",
        'res_model': 'diaries_purchases',
        'target': 'current',
        'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}
    }
```

I need to send the value "my purchase" to the specific field called name of the view diaries_purchases, i guess by context, but my code not works, thanks for your help

Comment: How have you ended up with `"{'name': 'my purchase'}"` i.e. a string rather than a dictionary?

Comment: the field name is a char type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the context like this, by prefixing the field name with `default_`

```
def view_purchase(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'diary_purchase',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'context': {'default_name': 'my purchase'},
        'res_model': 'diaries_purchases',
        'target': 'current',
        'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your destination model (the on you open with your `view_purchase()` function). Access the context variable `self.env.context` there you should find your value. You should use a computed or default value on the field `name`.

```
def _get_name(self):
    self.name = self.env.context.get('name')

name = fields.char(string="Name",compute=_get_name,store=True)
```